# Is there any ID number to track error in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I want to ask that whether there a particular number denoted to track error in android studio?

take an example like 
HTTP codes
404-Page Not Found

Comment: you should check the response header.

Comment: You mean for exception?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are many many kinds of error that can occur in an Android (java) program, while some may have a specific error code, most do not.

There are definitions of Exceptions though like here: [exception list java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_builtin_exceptions.htm)

And if you want to categorize errors, you can also see what kind of error you are dealing with [error types](http://www.dickbaldwin.com/Cosc1315/Pf00120.htm), but this is much more abstract. Logical errors for instance, might not make your program crash.